# Data URI Automated Generator in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, api, uri

I'm developing an iOS app and would like to have a string of HTML code converted to a Data URL. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data URIs, they are like a type of `heredoc`, meaning they contain all the information in-line, but act as if they were from an external resource.

In this case, to generate the URI, you only need the header (which tells the browsers that it is a data uri and what type it is), and the data that you append upon it.

HTMLs have the type `text/html`, and the encoding we will be using for the data URIs is going to be base64.

So you can use:

```
$uri = 'data:text/html;base64,' . base64_encode($html);
```

Comment: Thanks you helped tremendously! :D